# Inline SVG in CSS doesn't work

Tags: html, css, svg

I use inline-SVG in CSS file to fill background for a div. But it didn't work. I test my SVG code is good. You can test by copy svg code to this https://www.rapidtables.com/web/tools/svg-viewer-editor.html

```css
#bgr{
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  background:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width="500" height="500"><path d="M340.8,98.4c50.7,0,91.9,41.3,91.9,92.3c0,26.2-10.9,49.8-28.3,66.6L256,407.1L105,251.6c-15.8-16.6-25.6-39.1-25.6-63.9 c0-51,41.1-92.3,91.9-92.3c38.2,0,70.9,23.4,84.8,56.8C269.8,121.9,302.6,98.4,340.8,98.4" style="fill:red;"/></svg>');
}
```

```html
<div id="bgr"></div>
```

Comment: Run it through a base64 converter, [this one](https://codepen.io/yoksel/details/JDqvs) works fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`. You may find more information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course):

```css
#bgr{
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  background:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"   width="500" height="500"><path d="M340.8,98.4c50.7,0,91.9,41.3,91.9,92.3c0,26.2-10.9,49.8-28.3,66.6L256,407.1L105,251.6c-15.8-16.6-25.6-39.1-25.6-63.9 c0-51,41.1-92.3,91.9-92.3c38.2,0,70.9,23.4,84.8,56.8C269.8,121.9,302.6,98.4,340.8,98.4" style="fill:red;"/></svg>');
}
```

```html
<div id="bgr"></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can convert it to base64 img, there're a bunch of online tools that can do it, this por example:

http://b64.io/

```css
#bgr{

  width:500px;
  height:500px;
background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIyMDAiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwIiB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiPiAgIDxyZWN0IHdpZHRoPSIyMDAiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwIiBzdHJva2U9ImJsYWNrIiBzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg9IjYiIGZpbGw9ImdyZWVuIi8+PC9zdmc+);
  );
}
```

```html
<div id="bgr"></div>
```

Comment: `You need to` --> he can but he don't **need**

Comment: true, language mistake